# Shopify problem : Payment gateway isn't setup to test orders

Tags: shopify

**Payment gateway isn't setup to test orders. This store can't accept real orders or real payments.**
I add a custom payment to Shopify and when I place order using method the error appears
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NJq6.png)

Comment: Are you using it on development store or 14 days trial account?

Comment: i use it on development store

Comment: i create a development store on shopify partners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test real payment methods on development stores.
This is because development stores have limitations on them to make sure that they are used only for development.
[image]

You'll have to transfer the ownership to your client. You can find more information [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/partners/dashboard/managing-stores/hand-off-development-stores).